# Win32/.net: How do I determine the currently used language/localization/culture of a process?

Tags: .net, winapi, process, culture

My first attempt was using the System.Diagnostics.Process.ProcessName to find the executable and System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.Language to determine the language.

This does not work for e.g. Microsoft "Excel.exe" 2007. If you have a look at the file properties in explorer you will see the language is set to "Language Neutral" even if the UI is actually showing german.

How can I find out the shown language, preferably at runtime by inspecting the process/exe?

Comment: To clarify, you want to write a program that can determine the  the culture settings for some *other* process?

Comment: Exactly right. If I run a german version of Excel on an english windows, the answer to my question would be german.

Comment: I don't see any way to do it. The Windows API function `GetThreadLocale` returns the locale of the current thread. I don't see a function anywhere that will let you determine the culture of some other thread. Not saying there is one, just that I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In all the applications that I've worked on, we just use the system language, found by checking

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx
for more information

I don't know if any specific process has a language associated with it like a system does.

Comment: Thx alot. Unfortunately I am on an english windows and use an german excel. System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture just shows the currently selected OS culture, not the one of the inspected application.

Comment: Culture info is thread-based. That is, each thread can have a different `CurrentCulture` value and `CurrentUICulture` value. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Comment: Thx Jim. The problem is I tried using .net Diagnostics and ended with System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread which had no property CurrentUICulture. Any chance to get there, maybe through win32 API?